# Remove parent theme action in child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I have create Child theme from `Shophistic Lite` theme.

I want to remove an action in child theme.

**// wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\content-product.php**
    ...

```
/**
 * woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_title - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );

/**
 * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );

/**
 * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close - 5
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );

...
```

**// \wp-content\themes\shophistic-lite\framework\functions\woocommerce_support.php**

```
...
/**
 * Adds the Switch View buttons
 */
function shophistic_lite_show_attribute() {
...
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'shophistic_lite_show_attribute', 15 );
...
```

**// \wp-content\themes\shophistic-lite-child\functions.php**

```
...
function remove_functions() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'shophistic_lite_show_attribute', 15 );
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' , 'remove_functions' );
...
```

I made it by this article: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-overriding-parent-theme-functions-in-your-child-theme--cms-22623
But it does no working for me. The `shophistic_lite_show_attribute` function is still executing.

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try the **`'init'`** hook instead for your remove action, to remove it at initialization:

```
function child_custom_actions() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'shophistic_lite_show_attribute', 15 );
}
add_action( 'init' , 'child_custom_actions' );
```

This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

**This code is tested and works** *(see below)*.

---

> **Update related to your comment:**

I have uploaded your theme **`Shophistic Lite`** in a test server, created a child theme.

**I have temporary changed** the function **on the main theme** in **`woocommerce_support.php`** file, to make it display something, without any special settings needs (and saved) this way:

```
/**
 * Adds the Switch View buttons
 */
function shophistic_lite_show_attribute() {
    echo '<p>BLA BLA</p>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'shophistic_lite_show_attribute', 15 );
```

And it displays on shop page this:

[image]

Then I have add the code of the first snippet above on **`function.php`** file of the child theme *(the same you have tried with the 'init' hook)*, **and it just works perfectly**, removing that "BLA BLA".

So may be you are trying to remove something else that is not generated by this hook…

Comment: I the tutorial I attached to my question is said: > "...you need to attach this function to a hook which will fire after the hook which the parent theme function is attached to..." I this context **this function** mean `remove_action`

Comment: By the way, I tried to use `init` hook - it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, I'm waiting for your answer. I tried  to use `init` hook again but no result.

Comment: @АртёмМатушенко Just tested, see the related update in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was trying to remove related product section from single product page. It was not the default related product section, it was specific to my theme (and so I had to remove action from parent theme).

Using `wp_loaded` hook worked fine, while `init` hook mentionned above didn't worked.

So finally, this code in my child theme is working fine:

```
function child_custom_actions() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded' , 'child_custom_actions' );
```

**Warning :** `woocommerce_after_single_product` hook is not the default hook for woocommerce related product section, it is specific to my theme, you might need to use `woocommerce_after_single_product_summary` hook.